# Where i can find Oberon modules for Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: module, ubuntu-16.04, oberon

I read Niklaus Wirth book and want try examples from this book.

And i try run simple Oberon hello world: http://groups.engin.umd.umich.edu/CIS/course.des/cis400/oberon/hworld.html#source

But get error:

```
$ obc -o hello Hello.m
"Hello.m", line 4: the interface file for 'Oberon' cannot be found
>          IMPORT Oberon, Texts;
>                 ^^^^^^

"Hello.m", line 4: the interface file for 'Texts' cannot be found
>          IMPORT Oberon, Texts;
>                         ^^^^^
```

Clearly i should install required modules. Quick googling don't give me answer. So where i can find this modules?

I install Oberon from this deb http://spivey.oriel.ox.ac.uk/corner/Installing_OBC_release_3.0

Answer (score 3):

The modules *Oberon* and *Texts* are typically associated with the Oberon operating system. The only library standard that I know of for freestanding Oberon compilers is "The Oakwood Guidelines for Oberon-2 Compiler Developers". Using module *Out*, the *Hello World* program should be as simple as

```
MODULE hello;

    IMPORT Out;

BEGIN
    Out.String("hello, world");
    Out.Ln
END hello.
```

I can also recommend the compiler OBNC which implements the latest version of the (original) Oberon language:

> https://miasap.se/obnc/